# I have a number that represents 40%. How do I get the whole?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know 8,000 represents 40% of X and I'd like to figure out X.

I can start by doubling 8,000 and that gets me 80% of the total.

10% of the 8,000 is 1,000 and I can add that twice to get the remaining 20%.

If 8,000 is 40% of X, then X is 18,000.

Is that right?

Comment: You're almost right.  Just some correction,  $10\%$ is $2000$ so you would have $20,000$ as final answer

Comment: Like always in math problems, mark $x=$ the unknown number. You know that $8~000$ represents $40~\%$ of an unknown number, that is ("40 per cent of an unknown number is 4000")
$$
0.4 x = 8~000
$$
Now it should be a lot clearer.

Comment: The easiest way is to divide by $0.4$ , as Matti explained.

Comment: If $8000$ is a $40$% of $X$, then $8000/X=0.4$. From here you can find $X$. Or you can reason like this: write under each other $8000-40$%, $X-100$% and do the cross multiplication. After that, you would be able to find $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with basic algebra.

Remember 40% $= \frac{40}{100}$

We are saying what number times 40% gives us $8000$,

$$8000=x\frac{40}{100}$$

$$800000=40x$$

$$20000=x$$

Comment: So let's see if I understand. We can replace 8000 with 12000 and the answer is 30000

Comment: oops sorry that was right

Comment: haha you got it! This can be done for any percentage in the same way and if you wanted to cross multiply you can

Answer (score 2):

$8,000$ is $40\%$ of the whole

Divide by $4$

$2,000$ is $10\%$ of the whole

Muliptly by $10$

$20,000$ is $100\%$ of the whole.

This answer doesn't really depend on algebra (but essentially the same) ,  using just your head.  But, like other answers suggest, mastering algebra would help you better to solve another problem.

Answer (score 1):

No. Note that $40\%$ of $X$ just means $0.4X$, and so $0.4X=8000$. Dividing by $0.4$ yields $X=20000$.

Your mistake was that if $8000$ is $40\%$, then $10\%$ is $2000$.

Generally, the first approach is preferable, because it'd work with any percentage.

Answer (score -1):

If:
$$
\begin{split}
    40\% &= 0.4\\
    8000 &\to 0.4\\
    x &\to 1
\end{split}
$$
then:
$$
   x = \frac{8000 \cdot 1 }{0.4} = \frac{8000}{0.4} = 20000
$$

Comment: For more check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three